# Organizing the position of widgetized areas in the backend

Tags: customization, widgets, admin, dashboard

Is there a way to position the widget areas in the WP admin -> Appearance -> Widgets page? I've arranged my register_sidebars function in the proper order however they seem to be displayed randomly.

```
$sidebars = array (
    'sidebar-about'         => 'About',
    'sidebar-wwd'           => 'What We Do',
    'sidebar-news'          => 'News',
    'sidebar-videos'        => 'Videos',
    'sidebar-careers'       => 'Careers',
    'sidebar-news'          => 'News',
    'sidebar-posts'         => 'Shared',
    'sidebar-press'         => 'Press Release',
    'sidebar-casestudy'     => 'Case Study',
);

foreach ( $sidebars as $id => $sidebar) {
    register_sidebar(
        array (
            'name'          => __( $sidebar, 'bonestheme' ),
            'id'            => $id,
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
            'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h3>',
        )
    );
}
```

Also, any recommended resources for custom WP backend development like this?

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and the order is coming fine as per the definition. Please note that it fills in first column and then starts with second column. So to cross check the order with your array, you have to go top to bottom in first column and then in second column. Below is how the sidebars come at my end.

[image]

Please let me know if I have misinterpreted the question.